# Create a ContextMenu for any instance of a given control type

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, contextmenu

I'm fairly new to WPF and I have a question regarding the "factorisation" of logic across all controls of the same type.

To be more precise, I want to have, for any instance of an Infragistrics DataGrid, a context menu with a "Export to Excel" button, without having to write any code every time I use the said grid. 
Also, if by default I'll always have an "Export to Excel" context menu item, I also want to be able to add more items transparently on a case by case basis.
A bonus would be to be able to remove the Export to Excel button on a specific instance.

My question is what is the best way of achieving this:

- Subclassing the DataGrid and adding the ContextMenu programmaticaly on "OnInitialized"? Problem: what about a grid where I want to add extra menu items... the XAML will override what's already there? Also I'd prefer not to have a subclass of my control, just directly use the control itself and use WPF to add the intended behavior.
- Using the "behaviors"? I could add a new attached property to this type of grid but not sure if that's a good practice
- Anything else?

I hope my question makes sense!

Note: this question is NOT about exporting to Excel, I know the way to do this with my control.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `List<MenuItem> DependencyProperty` (if you want to bind from `ViewModel`. If you simply want to assign from code behind then create simple CLR property) in your datagrid Control and bind/assign it to the list of additional `menuItems`. And in `event DataGridLoaded` event Add these additional `menuItems` to the Common MenuItems.I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's not quite what I wanted though, as I want to be the less disruptive as possible for the existing control (i.e. I don't want to change the existing "pages"). I ended up using the attached property solution, i'll post my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I used the attached property solution eventually. It's very clean and doesn't "pollute" the existing code. You just have to add a single line of XAML (see below) to add the export to excel ability to any data grid.

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid
                    x:Name="summary"
                    Behaviours:XamDataGridBehaviours.ExportFileName="plop.xls"
                    ActiveDataItem="{Binding Path=SelectedSummary}">
[...]
</igDP:XamDataGrid>
```

The attached property code itself is below:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using Infragistics.Documents.Excel;
using Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter;
using Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.ExcelExporter;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace MYCOMPANY.Plugin.Framework.Behaviours
{
    public class XamDataGridBehaviours
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ExportFileNameProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "ExportFileName",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(XamDataGridBehaviours),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnExportCommandChanged));

        private const string ExportToExcelHeader = "Export to Excel";

        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(XamDataGrid))]
        public static string GetExportFileName(XamDataGrid d)
        {
            return (string)d.GetValue(ExportFileNameProperty);
        }

        public static void SetExportFileName(XamDataGrid d, string value)
        {
            d.SetValue(ExportFileNameProperty, value);
        }

        static void OnExportCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var grid = d as XamDataGrid;
            var fileName = (string) e.NewValue;

            if (grid != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            {
                CreateExcelExportMenu(grid, fileName);
            }
            else if (grid != null && grid.ContextMenu != null)
            {
                SafeDeleteMenuItem(grid.ContextMenu);
            }
        }

        private static void CreateExcelExportMenu(XamDataGrid grid, string fileName)
        {
            var contextMenu = grid.ContextMenu ?? new ContextMenu();

            var exportToExcel = GetOrCreateMenuItem(grid, contextMenu, fileName);

            contextMenu.Items.Add(exportToExcel);

            grid.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
        }

        private static void ExportToExcel(XamDataGrid grid, string fileName)
        {
            var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog.FileName = fileName;
            saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = ".xls";
            saveFileDialog.Filter = "Excel spreadsheets (.xls)|*.xls";

            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                var exporter = new DataPresenterExcelExporter();
                exporter.Export(grid, saveFileDialog.FileName, WorkbookFormat.Excel97To2003);
            }
        }

        private static MenuItem GetOrCreateMenuItem(XamDataGrid grid, ContextMenu menu, string fileName)
        {
            foreach (var item in menu.Items)
            {
                if (item is MenuItem)
                {
                    var menuitem = item as MenuItem;
                    if (menuitem.Header.ToString() == ExportToExcelHeader)
                    {
                        menuitem.Command = new RelayCommand(o => ExportToExcel(grid, fileName));
                        return menuitem;
                    }
                }
            }

            var exportToExcel = new MenuItem();
            exportToExcel.Header = ExportToExcelHeader;
            exportToExcel.Command = new RelayCommand(o => ExportToExcel(grid, fileName));

            var icon = new Image();
            var bmImage = new BitmapImage();
            bmImage.BeginInit();
            bmImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"..\..\Images\excel.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            bmImage.EndInit();
            icon.Source = bmImage;
            icon.MaxWidth = 16;
            exportToExcel.Icon = icon;

            return exportToExcel;
        }

        private static void SafeDeleteMenuItem(ContextMenu menu)
        {
            MenuItem toDelete = null;

            foreach (var item in menu.Items)
            {
                if (item is MenuItem)
                {
                    var menuitem = item as MenuItem;
                    if (menuitem.Header.ToString() == ExportToExcelHeader)
                    {
                        toDelete = menuitem;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (toDelete != null)
                menu.Items.Remove(toDelete);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, whenever we set a non-null export file name to the grid, the code adds an export to excel item. If the file name ends up null, the code will try to remove the export item if it exists. This way, it shouldn't prevent having other items set by xaml and should stay transparent.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it in your XAML, you cand do:

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
     <!--Binding to your view model and the command is whatever your command name should be ->
     <MenuItem Header="Export to CSV" Command="{Binding Export}"/>
  </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

This allows your to add new objects to the context menu.